# Sum of indexed functors

Tags: haskell, category-theory

In [Slicing It](http://strictlypositive.org/slicing-jpgs/), Conor McBride develops indexed functors, and then describes their sums and products on a slide "Sum and Product" (slides are unlabelled, about 90% into the presentation). This slide begins

```
-- sum - choose between compatible structures
data (:+:) :: (i ->- o) -> (i ->- o) -> (i ->- o) where
    L :: s x :-> (s :+: t) x
    R :: t x :-> (s :+: t) x
instance (IFunctor s, IFunctor t) => IFunctor (s :+: t) where
    imap f (L sx) = L (imap f sx)
    imap f (R tx) = R (imap f tx)
```

In particular, this definition of `:+:` requires that both indexed functors have the same source index `i`. I wonder why this is the case. Can this be relaxed e.g. to allowing

```
-- sum - choose between compatible structures
data (:+:) :: (i ->- o) -> (j ->- o) -> (Either i j ->- o) where
    L :: s x :-> (s :+: t) x
    R :: t x :-> (s :+: t) x
```

where `i` and `j` are now different types?

Comment: Does that kind-check? I'd expect `L :: s x -> (s :+: t) ('Left x)`

Comment: @chi I think that's the answer the questioneer is looking for.

Comment: The short answer is: the uniform version keeps "choice" separate from "reindexing". The proposed thing is a *particular* reindexing, which can be coded readily. (By the way, I think chi is correct that there is a kind error but has fixed up the output index instead of the input index.) I'll try to write a proper answer later, but I've got to run.

Comment: If  this is intended to construct a comma category, then the original version seems categorically 'more correct'.

Answer (score 0):

@chi Thanks for your pointer. It turns out I was wrong -- my suggestion doesn't work, it is not possible to combine different inputs. However, it is possible to use `Either` for the output kinds, leading to the constructor @chi suggested:

```
data (:+:) :: (i ->- o) -> (i ->- u) -> (i ->- Either o u) where
    L :: s x o -> (s :+: t) x ('Left o)
    R :: t x u -> (s :+: t) x ('Right u)
```

Both the `:+:` and the `:*:` types on the slides take two types as arguments, i.e. essentially a pair of arguments. I believe my suggestion might work if they took an alternative (i.e. an `Either`) of type arguments, as in

```
data (:|:) :: Either (i ->- o) (j ->- o) -> (Either i j ->- o)
```